# onClick function not working in child of function reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to make an onClick function that works in the child of my function, but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why.

The onClick is meant to take the id from this:

```
const userCampaigns = [
{
    id: "curse-strahd",
    title: "Curse of Strahd",
    image: "/card-images/affroen and friends.jpg",
    description: "Scary vampire man does evil."
},
```

and return the results from this in one of my components:

```
const sesssions = {

"curse-strahd": [
    "session1",
    "session2",
    "session3",
    "session4"
]
```

Then make a card that displays the sessions.

These are my components:
[image]

My code:

```
export default function ChooseCampaign() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [displaySessionListId, setDisplaySessionListId] = useState("")

function clickHandler(displayId) {
    return () => {
        setDisplaySessionListId(displayId)
        setShow(!show)
    }
}

return <div style={{backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundImage: `url(${imgCaravan})`, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', position: 'fixed', top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%', marginLeft: '-8px' }}>
    <UserCampaignsList>
        {userCampaigns.map((val) => (<ChooseCampaignCard onClick={clickHandler(val.id)} key={val.id} id={val.id} image={val.image} title={val.title} description={val.description}/>))}
    </UserCampaignsList>
    <SessionCard sessionListId={displaySessionListId} />
</div>
```

}

Comment: You're invoking the click handler directly on render, which is not what you want. Instead, assign a function definition to onClick instead: `onClick={() => clickHandler(val.id)}`. Also ensure that `<ChooseCampaignCard>` actually passes the onClick prop to an element in its render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change onclick event call to below arrow function:

{userCampaigns.map((val) => (<ChooseCampaignCard onClick={**()=>clickHandler(val.id)**} key={val.id} id={val.id} image={val.image} title={val.title} description={val.description}/>))}

In clickHandler event, you are actually returning a function instead of executing statements. Either change your clickHandler function as below

```
function clickHandler(displayId) {
    setDisplaySessionListId(displayId)
    setShow(!show)
}
```

or call your click handler as below

```
<ChooseCampaignCard onClick={()=>clickHandler(val.id)()} key={val.id} id={val.id} image={val.image} title={val.title} description={val.description}/>
```

Comment: I did this, and it still didn't work, so I just checked components in react developer tools and saw that the entire onClick event is empty, so apparently I have a deeper problem that I don't what to do about. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have to change clickHandler as per my latest update above